# Email reply-to not working

Tags: email, gmail, reply

We have an application for sending emails with the reply-to address.
When we reply to the email, the reply-to email address is inserted in To(target) column only if the email was received from Gmail server but not working if I use any other mail server.

And the message details are :-

**For Gmail-**

```
*smtp.mailfrom=abhishek.manav09@gmail.com;
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2018 15:54:41 +0530 (IST)
From: Email <abhishek.manav09@gmail.com>
Reply-To: akshaykhurana97@gmail.com
To: akshaykumar@drishti-soft.com
Message-ID: <213945436.1.1535019881781@localhost>
Subject: CaseId-1535007334511:hello drishti
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_459502358.1535019879250"

------=_Part_0_459502358.1535019879250
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit*
```

**For other mail server -**

```
*smtp.mailfrom=support@nirmalbang.com
Received: from cc.nirmalbang.com (unknown [192.168.51.88]) (Authenticated sender: support) by mumbai.nirmalbang.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id B8FAF9C1D4E for <akshaykumar@drishti-soft.com>; Thu, 23 Aug 2018 17:02:57 +0530 (IST)
X-Intloopheader: 0
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2018 17:02:45 +0530 (IST)
From: support <support>
Reply-To: rajeshyadav@nirmalbang.com
To: akshaykumar@drishti-soft.com
Message-ID: <373728699.19.1535023965631@cc.nirmalbang.com>
Subject: CaseId-1534767184816:meramera
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_18_1180661698.1535023965621"
X-Netcore-MailScanner-Information: Please contact the ISP for more information
X-Netcore-MailScanner-ID: B8FAF9C1D4E.AB6D7
X-Netcore-MailScanner: Found to be cleanenter code here
X-MailScanner-From: support@nirmalbang.com
X-Spam-Status: No*
```

Comment: This is not a function of the remote server, but the remote client. My money is on a Microsoft client as your test case; others generally are slightly less challenged when it comes to adhering to basic RFCs. (But  e.g. Thunderbird and Gmail break some RFCs pretty recklessly, too.)